# Как сделать ровный текст в ответе у бота?

Tags: python, telebot

На фото ответ бота.

- Как можно сделать сделать такой текст?
- Чтобы ровненько было и прочее?

[image: это сообщение бота какого то вуза]

Comment: Может Вы хотели сказать "Как изменить шрифт?"?

Comment: @qrts, нет, не шрифт, именно вопрос такой: как можно в код бота записать текст так, чтобы он, при ответе бота пользователю, выглядел именно так, как на фото, так как если просто в код запихнуть текст, получится кривой текст

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Накидал Вам на скорую руку копию "макета", который Вы предоставили. Советую ознакомиться с документацией по `parse_mode` для `html` или `Markdown`, что позволит Вам в дальнейшем создавать "ровные тексты".

Так же, в дальнейшем, настоятельно рекомендую выносить текстовые массивы в переменные с перемещением их в отдельный файл. В данном примере оставил все наглядно, но в дальнейшем, это будет попросту некрасиво и захламляюще.

Вот код. Вам нужно обратить внимание лишь на фрагмент от `bot.send_message` в обработчике команды `/start`

```python
import telebot
from telebot import types

bot = telebot.TeleBot('{Ваш токен}')

# Обработчик команды /start
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    back_button = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Вернуться назад', callback_data='back')
    keyboard.add(back_button)
    # Фрагмент отформатированного текста, который Вас интересует
    bot.send_message(chat_id=message.chat.id,
                     text=f'<b>Справка 086-У</b>\nДля подачи документов обязательна справка №086-У на следующие направления:\n\n<b>13.03.02</b> Электроэнергетика электротехника\n\n<b>19.03.02</b> Продукты питания из растительного сырья\n\n<b>35.03.06</b> Агроинженерия\n\n<b>36.05.01</b> Ветеринария\n\n<b>23.05.01</b> Наземные транспортнотехнологические средства',
                     reply_markup=keyboard, parse_mode='html')


@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: call.data == 'back')
def back_callback(call):
    bot.send_message(chat_id=call.message.chat.id, text='Вернулись назад')


bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Вот, как это может выглядеть еще:

```python
bot.send_message(chat_id=message.chat.id,
                     text=f'<b>Справка 086-У</b>\nДля подачи документов обязательна справка №086-У на следующие '
                          f'направления:\n\n<b>13.03.02</b> Электроэнергетика электротехника\n\n<b>19.03.02</b> '
                          f'Продукты питания из растительного сырья\n\n<b>35.03.06</b> '
                          f'Агроинженерия\n\n<b>36.05.01</b> Ветеринария\n\n<b>23.05.01</b> Наземные '
                          f'транспортнотехнологические средства',
                     reply_markup=keyboard, parse_mode='html')
```

Или же какой-то такой "креативный" подход, только учитывайте, что при вынисении этих переменных в отдельный файл, Вам нужно будет импортировать этот файл и ссылаться на него:

```python
import telebot
from telebot import types

bot = telebot.TeleBot('{Ваш токен}')

# Тексты, которые находятся в переменных и могут быть вынесены в отдельный файл
# Заголовок
title = '<b>Справка 086-У</b>\n'

# Описания со специальностями
directions = 'Для подачи документов обязательна справка №086-У на следующие направления:\n\n'
directions += '<b>13.03.02</b> Электроэнергетика электротехника\n\n'
directions += '<b>19.03.02</b> Продукты питания из растительного сырья\n\n'
directions += '<b>35.03.06</b> Агроинженерия\n\n'
directions += '<b>36.05.01</b> Ветеринария\n\n'
directions += '<b>23.05.01</b> Наземные транспортнотехнологические средства'

keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
back_button = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Вернуться назад', callback_data='back')
keyboard.add(back_button)

# Красивая отправка сообщения, без ничего лишнего :)
bot.send_message(chat_id=message.chat.id, text=title + directions, reply_markup=keyboard, parse_mode='HTML')

@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: call.data == 'back')
def back_callback(call):
    bot.send_message(chat_id=call.message.chat.id, text='Вернулись назад')

bot.polling()
```

Comment: спасибо, все сработало)

Comment: Это прекрасно, успехов :)